# Default list of Quicklook Plugins for a fresh LION install? What QL plugins "should be" in /System/Library/Quicklook/?

Tags: defaults, quicklook

This is an easy one for you all. I simply need people to list what Quicklook plugins they have installed in `/System/Library/QuickLook`.

I ask because I have a QL plugin named: `Icon.qlgenerator` in my system's quicklook folder and I do not think it should be there. Even a google search of "Icon.qlgenerator" turned up only a couple hits and they were no help.

All in all: I need members to 1) help me out and simply list which QL plugins they have in their system/library/quicklook folder (everyone should have the same.)
2) If Icon.qlgenerator is not supposed to be there, does anyone have any idea where this could have come from? Did previous versions of OS X's `/System/Library/QuickLook` directory contain `Icon.qlgenerator`?

Maybe I am freaking out and it should be there but if that was the case I think google would have found me some better info. [Google Search for "Icon.qlgenerator"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Icon.qlgenerator%22)

Thanks, we'll go from here. If it's not supposed to be there I will drop some more questions about determining what uses this ql plugin etc...

File in question: `/System/Library/QuickLook` - Modification date: 4/12/12, Creation date: 4/12/12, last used: 4/12/12... version 3.2

Answer (score 1):

I have Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4, and that file is present. The file is copyrighted by Apple ("3.2, Copyright Apple Inc. 2007-2011").

Looking at the content of its info.plist file, I see that its purpose is generating a preview for files with a content type UTI equal to com.apple.iconset, which (as far as I remember) is the type of files containing a set of icons.

The computer I am using is a Mac Mini middle 2011. I don't actually remember if It came with Mac OS X 10.7 already installed, or it came with Mac OS X 10.6, and then I installed Mac OS X 10.7. I have also installed Xcode.
Probably that can explain why some computers don't have that plugin, and some computers have it. It could also be the difference is caused from installed software, or an update of the operating system.

I would not say the plugin should not be there. It is not a file created from malware, or viruses to cause any issue with your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fresh Lion install and the only file in `/System/Library/Quicklook` is:

```
iWork.qlgenerator
```

*Note: I do not have iWork installed*

I have a MB running Snow Leopard and while it does have a number of files under the folder in question, `Icon.qlgenerator` is *not* one of them.

There is no harm in simply moving the file if it will put your mind at ease.  The most harm that moving it could do is give a blank preview when using quick look (or potentially CoverFlow).

Comment: Yeah, I am going to move it out later and see what happens. I think it is there because I use a qlgenerator for previewing files with no extension.